# How to loop custom post type using while loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am having  issues in looping custom post type using while loop. Yes, I am display data without error but `the_ID()` function is being printed outside specific id i.e id="panelsStayOpen-heading'.the_ID().'" as shown in an image.
**issue**

```
function displayFaqs() {
        
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'advance_faq',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();
    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="accordion-item">';
            echo ' <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-heading'.the_ID().'">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapse'.the_ID().'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapse'.the_ID().'">'
                      . get_the_title() . '
                    </button>
                  </h2>';
            echo '<div id="panelsStayOpen-collapse'.the_ID().'" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"       aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-heading'.the_ID().'">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                  '
                      .the_content() . '
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
      return $contents;

}
add_action( 'init', 'a_register_shortcodes');
```

[image]
How do I fix the issues to print in a specific id without printing outside

Comment: Please ask one question per post

Comment: @M.Eriksson its done, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the_ID() with get_the_ID() because you are already using echo.

the_ID() used to print out the post_id directly and get_the_ID() returns the id.

Comment: This answer would most likely solve their issue. It would, however, be a better answer if you explained a bit more why it would help, and what the differences between those functions are.

Comment: I did not know there is difference between get_the_ID() and the_ID(), thank you. If you don't mind How do I  make the first accordion tab show and the rest closed?

Comment: the_ID() used to print out the post_id directly and get_the_ID() return the id.

Comment: Try making a counter variable before while loop or  Ask another question I'll post answer  with the your code.

Comment: @zillionera_dev I am doing like this  `class="accordion-collapse collapse '.(($i++)?'show').'" ` but has some errors `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ")"`, any pointer?